# Second derivative test in the Hilbert space case

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, operator-theory, frechet-derivative, extreme-value-theorem

Let

- $H,E$ be $\mathbb R$-Hilbert spaces;
- $f\in C^2(\Omega)$;
- $c\in C^2(\Omega,E)$;
- $M:=\left\{c=0\right\}$;
- $x\in M$ be a local minimum of $f$ constrained on $M$, i.e. $$f(x)\le f(y)\;\;\;\text{for all }M\cap N\tag1$$ for some open neighborhood $N$ of $x$.

Now, let $$\mathcal L(x,\lambda):=f(x)-\langle\lambda,c(x)\rangle_E\;\;\;\text{for }\lambda\in E.$$ As shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3418026/47771), $${\rm D}_1\mathcal L(x,\lambda)={\rm D}f(x)-\langle\lambda,{\rm D}c(x)\rangle_E=0\tag2$$ for some $\lambda\in E$ and, under the identification $\mathfrak L(H,\mathbb R)=H'\cong H$, $${\rm D}f(x)\in\left(\ker{\rm D}c(x)\right)^\perp=\overline{\operatorname{im}\left(({\rm D}c(x))^\ast\right)}\tag3.$$

> I would like to conclude $$\langle{\rm D}_1^2\mathcal L(x,\lambda)u,u\rangle_H\ge0\;\;\;\text{for all }u\in\ker({\rm D}c(x)).\tag4$$ (Note that ${\rm D}_1^2\mathcal L(x,\lambda)\in\mathfrak L(H,H')\cong\mathfrak L(H)$.)

We should be able to argue in the following manner: Let $u\in\ker({\rm D}c(x))$. [We know](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3416968/47771) that there is a $\varepsilon>0$ and a $\gamma\in C^2((-\varepsilon,\varepsilon),M)$ with $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma'(0)=u$. By definition of $x$, $0$ is a local minimum of $f\circ\gamma$ and hence $$0\le(f\circ\gamma)''(0)=\left({\rm D}^2f(x)\gamma'(0)\right)\gamma'(0)+{\rm D}f(x)\gamma''(0)\tag5.$$ On the other hand, $${\rm D}_1^2\mathcal L(x,\lambda)={\rm D}^2f(x)-\langle\lambda,{\rm D}^2c(x)\rangle_E.\tag6$$

> Now we somehow need to incorporate $(2)$ and $\gamma'(0)\in\ker({\rm D}c(x))$. How can we do that?

Comment: You should improve the notation: $Dc(x)\in L(E,E)$, so $\langle \lambda,Dc(x)\rangle_E$ makes no sense. Same for the second derivatives.

Comment: @daw To me it makes perfectly sense. Writing $\langle\lambda,{\rm D}c(x)\rangle_E$ instead of $E\ni x\mapsto \langle\lambda,{\rm D}c(x)x\rangle_E$ is the same as writing $f$ instead of $x\mapsto f(x)$ for any function $f$.

Answer (score 1):

You know $c(\gamma(t))=0$. Differentiating twice with respect to $t$ yields
$$
 D^2c(\gamma(t))(\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t))  + Dc(\gamma(t))\gamma''(t)=0.
$$
Setting $t=0$ gives 
$$
 D^2c(x)(u,u)  + Dc(x)\gamma''(0)=0.
$$
Then from (2) 
$$
Df(x) \gamma''(0) = \langle \lambda, Dc(x) \gamma''(0)\rangle
= -\langle \lambda, D^2c(x)(u,u) \rangle.
$$

Comment: You obtain $D^2c(\gamma(t))(\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t))  + Dc(\gamma(t))\gamma''(t)=0$ by arguing that $c\circ\gamma$ is identically $0$ in a neighborhood of $t$, right?

Comment: I'm asking cause I wonder which assumptions we really need. In order for $(2)$ to hold it's sufficient that $f$ is Fréchet differentiable (not necessarily *continuously* Fréchet differentiable) and $c$ is continuously Fréchet differentiable. Moreover, in order to conclude $(f\circ\gamma)''(0)\ge0$, we only need that $f$ is twice Fréchet differentiable at the particular $x$ (not necessarily on all of $Ω$). Now in order for the identity in my previous comment to hold, it should suffice to further assume that $c$ is twice Fréchet differentiable at the particular $x$ as well. What do you think?